# Sci-Fi short story collection

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to track down a collection of Sci-Fi short stories that I owned in the mid 1980s.  Brief descriptions of some of the tales are as follows:

- Aliens are trying to land on Earth & are in contact with a ground station.  Coordinates are given to land but the craft cannot be seen.  It turns out the aliens are tiny & can't be seen.
- An astronaut is in a spaceship heading out into deep space when he hits something.  Turns out he has reached the edge of the universe.
- Boy & girl on another planet.  Boys name is alternate spelling of Michael ("Mykyl" ?)

Hopefully someone can help.
Cheers

Comment: I have this one at home - will find out for you this evening

Answer (score 9):

The first short story you describe above is "Pictures Don't Lie" by Katherine Maclean. You can find bibliographic data for it [here](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56212), which should narrow things down considerably. Sorry, but I don't recognise either of the other two stories, so I can't triangulate.

Comment: Hi Mike, spot on with that one.  The story is indeed "Pictures Don't Lie".  From the link you supplied, I have narrowed the collection choice down to two books (both covers are familiar to me).  I'm going to order both books as there is a posibility the tales I'm remembering are spread across both books.       Many thanks for all the help

Comment: @Mike: Did you ever figure out which book it was?

Answer (score 3):

The Mykl story is [Escape From Splatterbang](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?19383), AKA Flamers, by Nicholas Fisk.

It seems that an excerpt from the novel has been published as a short story in at least one collection, under the title [Marooned On Splatterbang](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?302733). That book doesn't have *Pictures Don't Lie*, though.

Maybe the OP is conflating two different books.

The Mykl story is a duplicate of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/43470/ya-novel-from-pre-1980-set-on-the-moon-in-which-a-boy-is-rescued-by-space-gypsie), by the way.