# Juvenile SF novel starting with a lost boy entering a dome run by an AI called "Ego"

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

The other day, something reminded me of the start of a juvenile science fiction book I checked out from a public library sometime in the early 1980s (say, between 1980 and 1984, I estimate). I know I found it in the kid's section, but it was mostly text instead of being, say, a storybook with colorful illustrations on each page. (If it helps, I think it was in the same section as the "Three Investigators" books, written by Robert Arthur, which I was reading around that time.)

English language. Hardcover. I remember nothing about the author (not even whether I'd previously read anything else by the same person).

The problem is that at this moment I only remember the plot of the first chapter or two. I'm hoping someone else will recognize this from the description.

**Plot Points**

1. The story is written in the third person, and the protagonist is a boy (pre-teen, I'm thinking). As the story opens up, I believe he somehow finds himself stranded on the surface of an asteroid or uninhabited planet. I have the idea that he'd been separated from his parents, and somehow had landed alone on this ball of rock, but I don't think his parents were dead. (I don't remember the story being that depressing.)
2. I think the boy is wearing a space suit, but I could be wrong. Possibly the air on the surface of this astronomical body is breathable. At any rate, the boy somehow finds what is obviously a man-made structure; I believe in the shape of a large dome. He enters through the door or airlock (depending on the atmospheric conditions).
3. Once inside, the boy is startled when a voice speaks to him. It turns out to be the Artificial Intelligence (probably not called by that exact phrase within the text) which is basically the permanent caretaker of this place. Either the place had been set up as an aid station for exactly such emergencies as a human being somehow getting stranded in this neighborhood, or else it had been built for some other purpose which may have already been served. (I don't remember getting the feeling that the AI was directing an active mining operation, for instance.)
4. The AI introduces itself as "Ego." One reason that name sticks with me is that I was so young at the time that, while I may have seen the word before, I was not entirely clear on its precise meaning. I think the AI briefly defines the term to explain why this is a suitable name for it. Ego is quite willing to help a human in distress, but has very limited resources available. (For instance, I don't think it had a fully functional spaceship parked in a hangar nearby, nor could it instantly establish a radio conversation in realtime with any humans located elsewhere.)
5. The kid does not spend the rest of the story just sitting in the dome waiting to be rescued. I'm sure he visits other places and has other adventures before an obligatory happy ending is provided, but I can't remember details of those adventures. (I don't even remember if "Ego" got to do anything in the plot after the first couple of chapters.)

Does anyone remember a piece of juvenile science fiction which started out along these lines?

Note: This particular "Ego" did **not** have anything to do with the Marvel Comics character known as "Ego the Living Planet." And thus it has no connection with the MCU version of that concept which was recently featured in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2* (with Ego played by Kurt Russell).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could this be Nicholas Fisk's "[Flamers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?187115)" (a.k.a "[Escape from Splatterbang](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1087765.Escape_From_Splatterbang)")? To borrow from an [earlier answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/43470/ya-novel-from-pre-1980-set-on-the-moon-in-which-a-boy-is-rescued-by-space-gypsie/46413) (bolding mine):

> The novel was set on Splatterbang, a planet with an atmosphere unbreathable to humans, a dying ecosystem, and some very dangerous native life forms: the titular "Flamers", which resembled living fireballs that were attracted to and consumed metal. The boy and the girl were named Mykl and Amina respectively. The base in which Mykl takes refuge after being marooned on Splatterbang is operated by an **AI named "Ego"**. After learning Mykl's name, Ego says that it's a very old name that used to be spelled "Michael". The scene with the image of the girl on the monitor occurs in the base, before he meets Amina. Ego says that the image is old data that shouldn't be there, but offers to give her a voice and personality as a companion for Mykl. The first attempt to rescue Mykl and Amina failed because the cable used to lower the rescue pod was made of metal and was attacked and consumed by the Flamers. Another detail that I remember is that **spacesuits** were usually equipped with a device called a "strong right arm" that provided enhanced strength; in one scene, Mykl uses it to break a mechanical lock with his thumb.

Fisk is alphabetically close to "Arthur". I found this one by searching for *book "ai named ego"*.

Comment: That sure sounds like it. The bit about Ego telling the boy his name used to be spelled differently (i.e. what I'd call the "normal" spelling) sounds suspiciously familiar. Although I can't for the life of me remember anything about a girl. Still don't recognize the name "Nicholas Fisk," but perhaps it's time to brush up, if I can find some of his stuff. (Wikipedia says he wrote a lot of books.) Incidentally, I put in that note about "Guardians of the Galaxy" because that was what kept coming up when I tried searching this site for references to "Ego."