# Tiny spaceship crash-lands and is crushed

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

I need to know the name of a Film/story/book, not sure which.

- A space craft is going to crash-land on Earth
- The pilot is speaking with the government asking for a safe place to land that's not near any water or lakes as those will destroy him.
- The ship is guided to an open field but they can't find it because the craft is tiny.
- At the end of the story/film/book, one of the searchers accidentally treads on it!

Comment: It sounds like the story described in this book, but it doesn’t name it: http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=kInT9EHvKwwC&pg=PA278&lpg=PA278&dq=spaceship+trodden+on&source=bl&ots=a19qKMF1Lo&sig=MiWAQIEPjvsh7NwFvjcDhFk9ZI0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eCRAVOfxDeaP7Aa0oYGQBg&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=spaceship%20trodden%20on&f=false Black-and-white sci-fi film?

Comment: I believe that it was an old black and white episode of the Outer Limits or the Twilight Zone. I don't remember the title.

Answer (score 14):

That would be "Pictures Don't Lie" by [Katherine MacLean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katherine_MacLean), although based on your description I believe you're thinking of the 1962 TV episode based on the story. The reviews [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667676/reviews?ref_=tt_urv) mention all of the plot elements you describe.

> Something's wrong! The aliens claim to have reached our planet ... yet
>   they don't see anyone waiting for them, and the waiting humans don't
>   see the alien ship. Now the aliens claim to have landed in an ocean of
>   noxious chemicals, and they're being attacked by bizarre monsters.
>   Angrily, they accuse us of lying to them. The transmission fades as
>   the 'monsters' (from Earth, apparently) destroy the aliens.
>
> Eventually, the Earth people suss out what went wrong. **Although the
>   aliens look like humans, they are in fact much smaller than we are:
>   microscopic, in fact.** Their tiny spaceship landed in a rain puddle,
>   where it was devoured by protozoa

Comment: MacLean's "Pictures Don't Lie" was also identified as part of the answer to [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13139/sci-fi-short-story-collection).

Comment: This is not it, but it brings to mind Douglas Adams’ Hitchhiker’s Guide to the Galaxy, particularly the text game: “…the mighty ships tore across the empty wastes of space and finally dived screaming on to the first planet they came across - which happened to be the Earth - where due to a terrible miscalculation of scale the entire battle fleet was accidentally swallowed by a small dog.”